# How to cancel canplay event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, jquery-events, mediaelement

There is a button, which plays a audio when clicked. More over, when the audio starts to play, a function is executed happen. For this reason, I attached an event listener to an audio as shown below.

However, when user clicks the button before the audio starts to play, then the `audioResponse` is executed twice. In these cases, I want to cancel the first execution of `audioResponse`. Is there any way to achieve that?

The audio is created as below:

```
audio = new Audio;              
audio.src = url;                
div = $('#sound-div').get(0);               
div.appendChild( audio );   
audio.removeEventListener("canplay", audioResponse)
```

Audio is deleted each time I press click:

```
$('#sound-div').html('');
```

,each time I press click.

Comment: Please post more code, including the `HTML`.